# How to update new version file's on old version using NSIS

Tags: nsis, setup-deployment

In my system already installed old version of tool.
How to replace/update new version of tool's lib,file,dll etc with old version using **NSIS script**.
Thanks in advance.

P.S.: Sory for my bad english

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall the undesired version or worst case, just install on top of the existing install...

Comment: Hello Anders, Thanks for reply. I am new in NSIS. 
Do you have any reference for this. 
If yes please share with me

Comment: You provided very little information in your question so my answer is pretty generic.